# time dependent workflow action - email alert not sent and not in queue

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

The time dependent workflow actions for a workflow I use is an email alert. But neither am I getting any email alert nor is there anything in the queue after creating a case record which triggers the flow.
For Testing I placed an email alert under Immediate Actions, and that email alert was working fine. The issue seems to be only with the email alert that I placed under Time dependent workflow actions.

[image: The original workflow]

[image: Queue empty even after the workflow fired]

Comment: Will you explain a bit briefly about criteria of workflow @Chandan Mullick

Comment: There is a date field in case, Review Date, if its blank, the workflow fill fire. 
Criteria IsBlanck(Review_Date__c)

Comment: But in question it' showing other criteria.

Comment: Kindly check the 'Rule Criteria'. It says 'ISBLANK( Review_Date__c )'

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate action fills the date in, right? That makes the record not satisfy the condition anymore and the time based action is cancelled.

The record needs to satisfy criteria at the time of the time based action as well.

Answer (score -1):

You will get an email Alert when Review date is Autopopulated

Comment: I want to receive email email an hour after the workflow has been triggered.

Comment: Change your time trigger accordingly.@ChandanMullick

Comment: I intend to receive the email alert an hour after the workflow has been triggered.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that "reevaluate workflow rules" is checked on the field update.

Otherwise the field update that sets the date field won't cause the rule to reevaluate and set the time trigger.